# Linker error calling a particular function

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, android-studio-3.0, opus

I am using the `opus` library in an Android project. I have successfully linked to the library and can use the `opus_decode` function. But even though Android Studio does not throw any errors, the `opus_decode_float` throws an undefined reference error when I try to make the project with a linker command failed messages.

I have refreshed the linked `c/c++` files and restarted Android studio. Error still persists. Similar cases I have come across all mention linking/importing the header file where the `opus_decode_float` is defined but this is already imported as `opus_decode` which is defined in the same header file does not throw any linker errors.

Comment: It seems you have to learn about the differences between *declarations* and *definitions*. Functions are usually only *declared* in header file, and *defined* in the actual library file (that you need to link with).

Comment: Fair enough. I just went in search of the implementation and from first check  the failing function is not defined in the same file as the passing one. So that just might be it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks! So my CMake file imports another build file that has some configurations set that disabled the function. Whew! Can't accept a comment as answer though.